# Alternative to nested for-loop

Tags: python, pandas, performance, for-loop, optimization

I have a pandas df with some columns that contain blank values. I have a nested for loop that populates these columns with values by extracting these values from a list. All the rows of the given columns get the same value, and this is correct. The ordering here is important, as *col1* needs the value *val1*.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["", "", ""],
                     "col2": ["", "", ""],
                     "col3": ["Facebook, Instagram", "Facebook, Facebook", "Twitter"]})

Columns = ['col1', 'col2'] #list of column names that the code should iterate over
Values = ['val1', 'val2'] #list of values to be inserted in the given columns

for n in Columns:
    for i in df:
        df[Columns] = Values
```

Output:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   val1    val2    Facebook, Instagram
1   val1    val2    Facebook, Facebook
2   val1    val2    Twitter
```

My current code works, but is very slow on a lot of data. What can I do to improve it?

Comment: can you post the expected output

Comment: I posted the output

Comment: `for col, val in zip(Columns, Values): df[col] = val`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think simpliest is pass variables like:

```
df[Columns] = Values
print (df)
   col1  col2                 col3
0  val1  val2  Facebook, Instagram
1  val1  val2   Facebook, Facebook
2  val1  val2              Twitter
```

**Performance** for 100k rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["", "", ""],
                     "col2": ["", "", ""],
                     "col3": ["Facebook, Instagram", "Facebook, Facebook", "Twitter"]})

Columns = ['col1', 'col2'] #list of column names that the code should iterate over
Values = ['val1', 'val2'] #list of values to be inserted in the given columns

df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)


%timeit df[Columns] = Values
7.53 ms ± 40.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: @Johnny - I today update to pandas 1.1.1 and python 3.8, so it should be better performance

Comment: ```4.01 ms ± 39.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)```...Maybe it's the memory frequency gap.@jezrael

Comment: @Johnny - Also depends of PC, os... I use `print (pd.show_versions())` `commit           : f2ca0a2665b2d169c97de87b8e778dbed86aea07
python           : 3.8.5.final.0
python-bits      : 64
OS               : Windows
OS-release       : 7
Version          : 6.1.7601
machine          : AMD64
processor        : Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
byteorder        : little
LC_ALL           : None
LANG             : en
LOCALE           : Slovak_Slovakia.1250`

Comment: ```commit           : f2ca0a2665b2d169c97de87b8e778dbed86aea07
python           : 3.8.5.final.0
python-bits      : 64
OS               : Windows
OS-release       : 10
Version          : 10.0.18362
machine          : AMD64
processor        : Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel
byteorder        : little
LC_ALL           : None
LANG             : None
LOCALE           : Chinese (Simplified)_China.936```         Maybe you should try Win10

Comment: @Johnny - It seems similar PC

Answer (score 0):

Both loops (the outer and the inner) are unnecessary: `n` and `i` are never used and you are performing the same operation n*i times, thus the code is slow. Just get rid of the loops and simply use `df[Columns] = Values`.